# Table has no columns Error in the place of Visualization: Bar Chart

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I am loading the data using Ajax call.

```
function drawChart() {

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: '/PrimeRx/GetIsAliveChart',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: null,
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                chartData = response;
                alert(chartData);
            },
            failure: function (error) { alert(error); }
        });

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(eval(jsonData));

        var options = {            
            vAxis: { title: 'AliveDate', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red'} }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I am getting the proper data the alert(chartData) which i require to display.

I am returning StringBuilder Object from Json.
Could any one analyse the issue.
Data in the alert looks like below.

```
[['LastAliveDate','System','Site','Server'],
['10/8/2012 12:00:00 AM','Site1','Server1'],
['10/8/2012 12:00:00 AM','Site1','Server1']
]
```

Comment: Chart is not getting displayed and insted i am getting Table has no columns in the place of Chart.

Comment: I think [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-visualization-api/L4pAVQxk55U) is a related issue